# Can you prevent a Kubernetes job from being preempted?

Tags: kubernetes, preemption

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#non-preempting-priority-class) page describes how to make a non-preempting priority class in Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority-nonpreempting
value: 1000000
preemptionPolicy: Never
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class will not cause other pods to be preempted."
```

It is very clear that it what it does is to prevent the jobs with this priority class from preempting others. What if I want the opposite ? Is there an option in Priority Class (or jobs directly) to create Jobs that cannot be preempted ?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. For me I'd like to have 3 priority classes: low/medium/high. I want to be able to make high priority pods to preempt low priority pods, but leave medium priority pods intact. I can't find a way to make this happen. (And changing the order of priorities is not an option because when everything is on the queue I need it to be low<medium<high)